# Connecting RDS to EC2 through a PHP script

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a EC2 instance running Apache Server which I need to connect to RDS.
I have done all the configurations.

```
mysql -h xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u xxxxx -p
```

I am able to connect to MySql running on RDS by manually running this command.

But I need to access the MySql database from a PHP script on EC2. I am using this script:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
$output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

But when I run this (ec2instancehostIP/abc.php) I get null.

Can you please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Are you sure your EC2 instance has permissions to access the RDS one?

Comment: Yes all permissions are set to public.